# Multiple <div> not aligning and sitting on top of each other

Tags: html, css

my site is [cg-its.com](http://www.cg-its.com)

I can't seem to get the facebook social icon to sit nicely with the other icons.

I have tried using CSS to align it all, but it wants to sit on top of the other buttons for some reason!

Here is the HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="four columns">
    <?php if($data['text_callus'] != "") { ?>
    <div class="callus"><?php echo $data['text_callus']; ?></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="socialshare">
      <div class="facebookshare">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/ConradGoodmanIT" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
      </div>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/ConradGoodmanIT" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false" data-dnt="true">Follow @ConradGoodmanIT</a>
      <script>
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.async=true;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
      </script>
      &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
      <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width="120" data-href="http://www.cg-its.com"></div>
      <!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.___gcfg = {lang: 'en-GB'};

        (function() {
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.container .twelve.columns .socialshare {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

.container .twelve.columns .socialshare .facebookshare {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: inline;
 }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Not easily, its wordpress with loads of includes and CSS overrides

Comment: I can't seem to find anything that looks weird. What browser and version are you using, and can you add a screenshot of what your issue looks like?

Comment: Do you know that [`float` other than `normal` automatically makes the element `display: block`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/displaypositionfloat)? There is no point in setting it back `inline` as the computed value will still be `block`.

Comment: Looks like you used the solution by @DavidRandall and did not accept or upvote his answer. Please refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in help center.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain it (if somebody can, please post, then I'll remove this one), but if I put `overflow:hidden; height:20px` on both divs, the problem is gone (on firefox 26).

Looks like a bug to me...  I don't see how overflow could cause a top margin.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit to include explanation*
By setting both `.socialshare` `div`s to `inline-block` we are keeping both containers as block level element while allowing them to sit next to each other.

```
.container .twelve.columns .socialshare .facebookshare {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.container .twelve.columns .socialshare .othershare {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Of course I tried. I added the new properties in firebug and also in Chrome devtools. I now have:
`.container .twelve.columns socialshare {display: inline-block; float: right; margin-top: 0;}`

`.container .twelve.columns .socialshare .facebookshare {display: inline-block; margin-top: 10px; vertical-align: top;}`

`.container .twelve.columns .socialshare .othershare {display: inline-block;    margin-top: 10px;}`

Comment: I added the correct code in my answer above. The code in the comment was a dump from firebug, including the code I gave in my answer.

Comment: @Palec Thanks for the advice, I'm still learning how to use this most effectively. Thanks for pointing the discrepancy in my original answer. I originally set these to 0 in firebug and had closed the page before grabbing the code again for my first comment. Have edited my original answer based on your feedback.